# Why can't I scrape these urls?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a list of urls collected in a pandas dataframe called "initial". My task is to loop through each of these urls, collect all of their h1 and p tags, and output the findings in another dataframe called "Articles". See my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib import request
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Articles = pd.DataFrame()

for url in initial["url"]:
    Article=""
    request_site = Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
    html = urlopen(request_site)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')
    try:
        text_list=bs.find_all(['h1','p'])
    except HTTPError as e:
        Article=e
    except URLError as u:
        Article=u
    except AttributeError as a:
        Article=a
    for text in text_list:
        Article += "\n"+"\n"+text.get_text()
    Instance_LIST={"URL":[url],"Text":[Article]}
    Instance_DF = pd.DataFrame(Instance_LIST)
    Articles = Articles.append(Instance_DF, ignore_index=True)
```

This code works for most websites! Unfortunately, I’m encountering a few cases where a url seems to break the loop. No error is outputted. For whatever reason, a single url iteration appears to run indefinitely. Here are two example articles that break the loop:

1. https://www.miamiherald.com/news/local/community/miami-dade/north-miami/article257698933.html
2. https://www.fresnobee.com/news/local/article277216493.html

Same thing happens when I try to scrape the h1 and p tags of these websites individually via the following code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen('https://www.fresnobee.com/news/local/article277216493.html')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')

nameList = bs.find_all(['h1','p'])
for name in nameList:
    print(name.get_text())
```

What is happening in these cases? Why can't I scrape these websites?

Comment: This also hangs for me with the code you've written.

Comment: the code fails to handle a URL that is not reesposive. This will break the loop. Secondly concurrent requests would be much faster with `threading` or `asyncio`....

Answer (score 1):

Same issue as here
[hangs on open url with urllib (python3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768441/hangs-on-open-url-with-urllib-python3)

it's the urlopen line that's hanging. Solution mentioned in the above thread  (adding headers to spoof a browser making the request) should help.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = urllib.request.Request(
    "https://www.fresnobee.com/news/local/article277216493.html",
    data=None,
    headers={
        'User-Agent':"PostmanRuntime/7.6.0"
    }
)
html = urlopen(req)

bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')

nameList = bs.find_all(['h1','p'])
for name in nameList:
    print(name.get_text())
```

Comment: My first block of code contains values for headers: 
headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

Still, I changed my code to what was in the thread you posted:
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'

Still doesn't work.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show the code that worked for me. I used a postman user-agent header

Comment: So I've found another instance where the code breaks...See this website:

https://lenouvelliste.com/article/238268/trafic-darmes-mandat-damener-contre-le-president-permanent-de-leglise-episcopale-dhaiti

I believe the loop breaks due to cookies...Any ideas how to effectively navigate instances like this?

Comment: You should be able to add cookies to a urllib.request.Request object with the add_header function. For example:

a_request = urllib.request.Request("https://lenouvelliste.com/article/238268/trafic-darmes-mandat-damener-contre-le-president-permanent-de-leglise-episcopale-dhaiti")
a_request.add_header("Cookie", "cookiename=cookievalue")